# Chrome Browser does not reload Nanogallery2 javascript upon refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nanogallery

When I try to reload the following code in Safari, it works well, but `chrome` browser does not reload `Nanogallery2` javascript upon refresh.

Any help is appreciated!

Sample Code attached:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/nanogallery2/dist/css/nanogallery2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/nanogallery2/dist/jquery.nanogallery2.min.js"></script>
```

```
<h1>Gallery made with nanogallery2</h1>

<div data-nanogallery2='{
    "itemsBaseURL": "http://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/samples/",
    "thumbnailWidth": "200",
    "thumbnailAlignment": "center"
  }'>
  <a href="berlin1.jpg" data-ngthumb="berlin1t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">Berlin 1</a>
  <a href="berlin2.jpg" data-ngthumb="berlin2t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">Berlin 2</a>
  <a href="berlin3.jpg" data-ngthumb="berlin3t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">Berlin 3</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Make a hard refresh? Otherwise, yes, the browser will attempt to load it from its cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Seems like Cahe issue. Remove your browser Cache and check***

As it's working for me and i am checking in [***Google Chrome Version 61.0.3163.91 (Official Build) (64-bit)***](https://prnt.sc/hxxyc7)

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/nanogallery2/dist/css/nanogallery2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/nanogallery2/dist/jquery.nanogallery2.min.js"></script>
<h1>Gallery made with nanogallery2</h1>

<div data-nanogallery2='{
    "itemsBaseURL": "http://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/samples/",
    "thumbnailWidth": "200",
    "thumbnailAlignment": "center"
  }'>
  <a href="berlin1.jpg" data-ngthumb="berlin1t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">Berlin 1</a>
  <a href="berlin2.jpg" data-ngthumb="berlin2t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">Berlin 2</a>
  <a href="berlin3.jpg" data-ngthumb="berlin3t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">Berlin 3</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is working for me too. I am using **Google Chrome Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)**